# Why doesn't my titan fall where I point?

Tags: titanfall-2

On the Xbox One, if I aim my sights at a spot and call my titan, it will invariably land in a completely different location. This sucks when I'm trying to drop it on another titan.

Is there some mechanic that I'm completely unaware of that dictates where it falls?

Comment: Does your titan fall somewhere else far away from where you pointed, or does it only stray a bit from where you pointed?

Answer (score 6):

A titan will not drop on a location that is partially or fully obstructed by static scenery, or is too small to fit a titan crouched down.

If the game has space to drop the titan on the roof of a building it will, otherwise it will choose the closest open location with enough room to drop a titan.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that obstructions may exist overhead too.  These won't be so obvious until you look up.

Comment: @camelCase Which is what I meant by static scenery

Answer (score 4):

Dropping a titan is tricky business. Especially when you are trying to land it on another titan.

A quick checklist:

- Look up! If there is not an opening to the sky then the titan will land elsewhere along the line drawn from you to where a bullet would hit the ground were to you to fire one.
- Look down! Aiming at the ground with your gun sight is the best possible way to get a titan to drop right on the dot.
- Look around! If there is anything within a decent radius of the place your gun sight is aimed then the titan will drop somewhere else further along the line drawn between you and where your gun is aimed (rarely horizontally off, if the calculation hits the end of the map it may track by closest distance to where it would have hit the end of the map).

For example, here you can see me target the ground with my Mozambique and then call the titan to fall directly on the Tone (with a little satchel distraction as well).

[image]

Comment: Please note that on May 15, 2023, [Imgur will remove content that is not tied to a user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). This may affect the media you included in your post since it was not uploaded to SE Imgur. I recommend that you reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You will need to edit the media to make it smaller than 2 MiB, which is the maximum size allowed by SE Imgur.